# How do I insert a record from one mongo database into another?

Tags: mongodb

As far as I see all commands operate on the same database in mongodb. I want to do something like this:

> db.mySourceCollection.find().forEach( function(x){ db.theDestinationCollection.save(x)} );

where `mySourceCollection` is on `liveDatabase` and `theDestinationCollection` is on `testDatabase`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `use` :-)

```
> var documents = db.mySourceCollection.find()
> use testDatabase
switched to db testDatabase
> documents.forEach(function(x){ db.theDestinationCollection.insert(x) })
```

`db` is used to refer to the currently connected database, however you can switch databases on the fly using the `use` command, as I've shown above.

Check out the `help` command in the shell -- it mentions this command and much more!

Comment: Thanks! I knew about use, but I wouldn't have thought of persisting the state in a variable. 

IMHO I'd expect a use() method on db for fluid use, e.g. db.use('sourceDb').collectionA.do(db.use('destDb').

Comment: It may happen that the database has UTF-8 characters. As this runs thru the client, if the client is the native one (for example for Ubuntu, `$ mongo --version` => `MongoDB shell version: 1.6.3`) it may lack UTF-8 and then the copy will fail. If this is the case and you don't want to put dirty into your server to recompile a new client, you can always recompile into a separate machine and do this job over the net connecting to a remote server. Nevertheless, the data will flow from the server to the client and back, so it can be slow. Anyway with a remote UTF-8 client, works!!!

Answer (score 14):

`use dbname` doesn't work in scripted mode (i.e. when scripting the shell with javascript), so you should use the `db.getSiblingDB()` method instead to reassign the 'db' variable, e.g.:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("otherdb")
```

More info here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell